# Change indentation from spaces to tabs by using Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, php, regex, preg-replace

I have the following `PHP` code which changes the indentation of `$html` from spaces to tabs (4 spaces are replaced by 1 tab).

```
<?php

function indent_with_tabs($html)
{
    $indented = preg_replace('/    /', "\t", $html);
    return $indented;
}

$html = <<<EOF
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea rows="10" cols="40">    Hello World</textarea>
    </body>
</html>
EOF;

$indented = indent_with_tabs($html);

$expected = <<<EOF
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea rows="10" cols="40">    Hello World</textarea>
    </body>
</html>
EOF;

$cmp = $indented === $expected;

var_dump($cmp);
```

Please, notice the tabs on the expected text (StackOverflow replace them with spaces XD)...

[image]

**My problem is:** it also replaces the 4 spaces in front of the text: `Hello World`.

I just need to get replaced the indentation spaces without replacing inner spaces.

Could you please provide the correct code for function: `indent_with_tabs(...)`?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `preg_replace('/(?:\G|^)\h{4}/m', "\t", $html);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```php
function indent_with_tabs($html)
{
    return preg_replace('/(?:\G|^)\h{4}/m', "\t", $html);
}
```

The regex matches

- `(?:\G|^)` - either start of a string or end of the preceding successful match or start of a line (`^` matches any line start position due to the `m` flag)
- `\h{4}` - any four horizontal whitespaces.